# How can I get an error when no results are fetched with DB query?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, pyramid

I'm trying to learn and advance with SQLAlchemy. Today I wanted to learn about exceptions it raises.

I'm working on a Pyramid based project, MySQL server (InnoDB) and SQLAlchemy.

I am trying to except all errors since `NoResultFound` error would not raise or print in console. So I except `exc.SQLAlchemyError`.

When I query my table and no results are found, it does not raise or catch or except anything whatsoever and continues operating.

**Questions:**

1. How can I and How should I query for `.all()` or `.one()`, and deal with
   the issue of not having any rows returned?
2. How can I and how should I deal with others SQL or System related errors? I would like to record them and observe them to fix issues.

My code is:

```
try:
    query = Session.query(MyTable).filter(Terms.column == my_string).all()
except exc.SQLAlchemyError, e:
    print e
    return False
```

(Instead of exc.SQLAlchemyError, I first tried NoResultFound, e)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Indeed this code will not raise an exception if no records are found. So instead you should throw your own exception:

```
import logging
try:
    records = Session.query(MyTable).\
        filter(Terms.column == my_string).all()
    if len(records) == 0:
        raise MyException('No records found')
except MyException, e:
    logging.info('No records found')
except exc.SQLAlchemyError, e:
    logging.exception('Some problem occurred')
```

Comment: Hello Jasper, thank you for this code and explanation. I understand your code and modified mine in a similar fashion to do what's needed. However I do not understand why it is not raising NoResultFound error? What's that error for if it's not raised when there are no results found? Doesn't make sense. ;-)

Comment: `NoResultFound` is raised when you use the `.one()` instead of `.all()`. Traditionally databases do not consider it an error to return an empty set when you ask for everything. SQLAlchemy helps you out and tells you there is an issue though when you ask for specifically one record.

Comment: query.all() returns a Python list; at that stage, there's no count() method. Also, if you meant to say query.count(), I'd also advise against calling *both* count() and all() - both emit a SQL statement.   If you've already called all() and got an empty list (i.e. mylist = query.all()), just check that list for non-empty: "if not mylist:  raise ...".

Comment: Jasper, it's been a few days but I wanted to say how much your code and explanation has helped. Thanks a lot.